# Stderr not showing in terminal

Tags: macos, fish

I'm not sure when or how I got into this state, but on my system, stderr doesn't seem to be displayed when I execute a command which leads to some error.

The most recent example is when I tried to run `node server` and had a syntax error in one of the required files. The command failed silently.

I'm using fish-shell 2.1.1, but I'm not 100 percent sure if this is a fish problem or some other configuration issue.

Other symptoms which may be related:
-previously I would run the `bash` command in fish to go into the bash shell. This no longer works. It hangs with no output
-running `csh` in fish gets me into the csh shell. Running `node server` failed silently as well, leading me to believe this might not be a fish issue.

Any help in troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Fish?

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thanks for taking the time to comment

Comment: The problem does seem to creep back. If anyone figures out a solution to this it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Step by step instructions of what you are doing exactly, virtual environments you are running, custom Fish functions, etc., would be hugely appreciated in order to help you.

Comment: Okay, might not get to this until the weekend, but I'll come back with more info.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly your problem, including that I couldn’t launch `bash`. I found that when I **commented out/removed** the following lines from my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
if test -z $rvm_bin_path
  exec bash --login -c "exec fish"
end
```

everything worked again. I don’t know how this got there, seems related to RVM. RVM still works fine with this code removed.

As a general approach, try to remove stuff from your fish config and see if changes the behavior.